# How to writte rspec test to test that helper method is available in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
#helper module
module UsersHelper
  #MY helper method
  def get_cms_content ()
  .
  end
end
```

---

```
#Controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
include UsersHelper
  def index
    #calling my helper method inside controller
    UsersHelper.get_cms_content()
  end
end
```

---

```
#rspec file
# i am not sure this is correct
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  def 
       it{expect(get_cms_content).to be(:available)}
  end
end
```

Please help me to write rspec testcase to check that My helper method is available in my controller.

Comment: Why do you want to test a Rails feature? test your feature...

Comment: The controller does'nt have any features It is having few methods with this same functionality.

Comment: Humm.. But as you said, that test is unnecessary.. You can test your own helper methods logics.. But not the one you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be writing specs for helper methods that are included via a mixin.

Instead, write specs for the module separately and just test for your controller's type.

In your case

```
RSpec.describe UsersController do
  it { is_expected.to be_a(UsersHelper) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Achrome I thought I need to test for all methods seperately. Now  I got it.